# Understanding reference before assignment error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Below code,

```
def is_leaf(tree):
    return type(tree) != list

def count_leaf(tree):
    if is_leaf(tree):
        return 1
    branch_counts = [count_leaf(b) for b in tree]
    return sum(branch_counts)
```

does not throw such error when referring `branch_counts` in expression `sum(branch_counts)`.

But below code,

```
def is_leaf(tree):
    return type(tree) != list

def count_leaf(tree):
    if is_leaf(tree):
        return 1
    for b in tree:
        branch_counts = [count_leaf(b)]
    return sum(branch_counts)
```

does throw such error when referring `branch_counts` in expression `sum(branch_counts)`.

In first case `branch_counts` is yet to be evaluated by computing list comprehension expression, Why error does not get thrown in first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tree is empty, `[]`, then the `branch_counts` variable isn't initialized.

To make the code equivalent to the first one, modify it thus:

```
def count_leaf(tree):
    if is_leaf(tree):
        return 1
    branch_counts = list()
    for b in tree:
        branch_counts.append(count_leaf(b))
    return sum(branch_counts)
```

Comment: So, you mean, in first case, `branch_counts` will get initialised under any circumstance. So, python interpreter understands this point and  dont have the error in first case. am I correct?

Comment: Yes.  The list comprehension might return an empty list though.  `sum` will return a `0` in that case.

Comment: another +1 for your alternate better solution. Except that my first case is purely functional(stateless). You solution is changing state.

Answer (score 0):

for your attention.. the first and second code are different, if you want it to do the same job then in the second code change the line to

```
branch_counts.append(count_leaf(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be printed in this case since there is nothing in `s`

```
a=[]
for s in a:
   print "hi"
```

Likewise for `"",{},()`

SO it second case if `tree` is empty the variable is not created

i.e.)

```
a=[]

for s in a:
    c=s


print (c)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-2cd6ee2c70b0> in <module>()
----> 1 c

NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

And for first case:

```
c=[s for s in a]
c
[]
```

And an error in your program is :

```
branch_counts = [count_leaf(b)]
```

creates only list of element one all time

It has to be initiated some where before in the loop  like `branch_counts = []`

then in the loop:

```
branch_counts.append(count_leaf(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, because you use a list comprehension, `branch_counts` gets initialized with an **empty list**:

```
>>> branch_counts = [count_leaf(b) for b in []]]
[]
```

In the second example, the `for` loop just doesn't run, because there is no `b` in `tree`. So `branch_counts` never gets assigned anything.

```
>>> for b in []:
>>>     branch_counts = [count_leaf(b)]
>>> sum(branch_counts)
NameError: name 'branch_counts' is not defined
```

Besides that, as others pointed out, in the second example branch_count gets newly assigned each time the loop runs (instead of adding something with `append()`).